# Laravel DB error when implemetning count() with havingRaw()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following eloquent query:-

```
$businessQuery = Business::select('businesses.id as business_id',
                                'users.id as user_id',\DB::raw('(
                                    6371 *
                                    acos(
                                        cos( radians( '.$request->current_latitude.' ) ) *
                                        cos( radians( address_books.latitude ) ) *
                                        cos(
                                            radians( address_books.longitude ) - radians( '.$request->current_longitude.' )
                                        ) +
                                        sin(radians('.$request->current_latitude.')) *
                                        sin(radians(address_books.latitude))
                                    )
                                ) as `distance`'))
                            ->join('users', 'businesses.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                            ->join('address_books', 'address_books.entity_id', '=', 'businesses.id');

$businessQuery = $businessQuery->where(array(
                                'businesses.is_deleted'=>'N',
                                'users.is_blocked'=>'N',
                                'users.is_active'=>1,
                                'address_books.entity_type'=>'M',
                                ));

if($request->business_name != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->where('businesses.business_name', 'like', '%' . $request->business_name . '%');
}
if($request->owner_name != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->where('businesses.owner_name', 'like', '%' . $request->owner_name . '%');
}
if($request->service_men != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->where('businesses.service_men', 'like', '%' . $request->service_men . '%');
}
if($request->service_women != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->where('businesses.service_women', 'like', '%' . $request->service_women . '%');
}
if($request->service_kids != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->where('businesses.service_kids', 'like', '%' . $request->service_kids . '%');
}   
if($request->distance != '')
{
    $businessQuery = $businessQuery->havingRaw('distance < '.$request->distance);
}
```

Now, if I am trying to get the count of the above Eloquent, I am getting error:

```
$totalCount = $businessQuery->count();
```

But when I am running the get() on $businessQuery, I am having no problem.

```
$businessResult = $businessQuery->get();
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I am getting:-

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;distance&#039; in &#039;
having clause&#039; (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `businesses` 
inner join `users` on `businesses`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join
 `address_books` on `address_books`.`entity_id` = `businesses`.`id` 
where (`businesses`.`is_deleted` = N and `users`.`is_blocked` = N and `users`.`is_active` = 1 and `address_books`.`entity_type` = M) 
having distance &lt; 200)
```

Comment: what's the error?? please include your error

Comment: what do you get by `dd($businessQuery->get())`??

Comment: why don't you use `$businessResult = $businessQuery->get();  $businessResult ->count(); `